# Making sense of the notation of Chain of critical points

Tags: real-analysis

This could be a silly question but nevertheless i am confused with the book i am referring to , the statement goes like this 
First Notations : 
$$C_i=\{x\in U : \frac{\partial^{j_1}....\partial^{j_n}}{\partial x_1^{j1}....\partial{x_n}^{j_n}}f(x)=0\} $$ for all $j$ with $j_1+j_2+....+j_n \le i$

The claim is $C_i \subset ....... C_1 \subset C_o$

But this doesn't seem to hold true  by taking simple example $f(x)=3x+x^2$ , $f'=2x+3$

$-3/2 \in C_1$ but not in $C_0$ 
I think my understanding is false here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a single variable. Then 
$$
C_0 = \{x \in U \mid f(x)=0\},
$$
while
$$
C_1 = \{x \in U \mid f(x) =0 \text{ and } f'(x)=0\}.
$$

Comment: Ok got it , that "and" makes a lot of difference . thanks :)

Comment: That "and" comes from the "$\le i$" instead of "$=i$" in the definition of $C_i$.